# How to make completely transparent background?

Tags: processing

I'm trying to generate a simple image using following code in Processing:

```java
int imageSize = 256;

void setup()
{
  size(256, 256);
  background(0, 0);
  noLoop();  
}

void draw()
{  
  float center = imageSize / 2.0;
  float maxDist = sqrt(128 * 128 * 2);

  for (int y = 0; y < imageSize; ++y)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < imageSize; ++x)
    {
      float dist = sqrt(pow(x - center, 2) + pow(y - center, 2));
      float factor = dist / maxDist;
      stroke(255, 255, 255, 255 - 255 * factor);
      point(x, y);
    }    
  }  

  save("output.png");  
}
```

As you can see from the code, the output image should be opaque in the center and transparent near the corners. However, the actual resulting PNG image is completely opaque:

[image: output image]

Is there any way to fix this issue? I.e. disable background somehow or force it to be completely transparent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a transparent frame, and by calling the `save()` function you're saving the current frame to a file. So that file will never have any transparency.

Instead, you should create your own `PGraphics` instance, which starts out as completely transparent. Then draw to that and use `PGraphics.save()` to save it to a file. Something like this:

```
PGraphics img;

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
  img = createGraphics(width, height);
}

void draw() {

  //draw to the image
  img.beginDraw();
  img.fill(255);
  img.ellipseMode(RADIUS);
  img.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
  img.endDraw();

  //optional: draw the PGraphics to the screen
  background(0);
  image(img, 0, 0);
}

//save the PGraphics to file
void mousePressed() {
  img.save("image_" + millis() + ".png");
}
```

Comment: It's quite strange that I can't get transparency by just using straightforward approach with `save()`. But anyway, your approach works fine. Thank you!

Comment: @Oleg It's not strange at all- you can't have a transparent frame, so saving the frame won't result in a transparency. But I'm glad you got it sorted!

Comment: Well, when I call `background(0, 0);` I explicitly ask for a fully transparent background. Processing API allows me to do this and it compiles and runs without any errors, but produces invalid result - opaque background. It just seems a little confusing for people who not familiar with Processing (like me).

Comment: @Oleg Don't know what to tell you. The frame does not support a transparent background. It's not an invalid result, it's the only valid result.